# Chinese Font - Some Characters Rendered Strangely (外，将）

Tags: characters, fonts

I am seeing some characters rendered strangely and would like to know what I can do to fix it.

In Google search bar, rendered strangely.  Inside translate box, rendered as desired:

[image]

In Google Docs, Firefox or Chrome:

[image]

In my terminal:

[image]

---

Is it perhaps trying to render in a Japanese font automatically?

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Browsers: Firefox & Chrome (seems to be browser independent)
- Tested in incognito mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Fixed in both my terminal and browser:**

[image]

Since I noticed this problem across all browsers and in my terminal, I figured the proper way to adress it would be at the system level.  I found a fix [here](https://gangmax.me/blog/2017/01/10/change-ubuntu-16-dot-04-default-chinese-font/) and have outlined the steps below.

1. Navigate to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`
2. Edit `64-language-selector-prefer.conf`, moving the **SC** suffixed fonts to the top of each preference list:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Noto Sans CJK SC</family>
            <family>Noto Sans CJK JP</family> # Original top choice
            <family>Noto Sans CJK TC</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>monospace</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Noto Sans Mono CJK SC</family>
            <family>Noto Sans Mono CJK JP</family> # Original top choice
            <family>Noto Sans Mono CJK TC</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

3. Edit `69-language-selector-zh-cn.conf`, adding `WenQuanYi Micro Hei` font to the top of each family (serif, sans-serif, monospace):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="lang">
            <string>zh-cn</string>
        </test>
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
            <string>WenQuanYi Micro Hei</string> # Added by me
            <string>HYSong</string>
            <string>AR PL UMing CN</string>
            <string>AR PL UMing HK</string>
            <string>AR PL New Sung</string>
            <string>WenQuanYi Bitmap Song</string>
            <string>AR PL UKai CN</string>
            <string>AR PL ZenKai Uni</string>
        </edit>
    </match> 
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </test>
        <test name="lang">
            <string>zh-cn</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
            <string>WenQuanYi Micro Hei</string> # Added by me
            <string>Noto Sans CJK SC</string>
            <string>WenQuanYi Zen Hei</string>
            <string>HYSong</string>
            <string>AR PL UMing CN</string>
            <string>AR PL UMing HK</string>
            <string>AR PL New Sung</string>
            <string>AR PL UKai CN</string>
            <string>AR PL ZenKai Uni</string>
        </edit>
    </match> 
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>monospace</string>
        </test>
        <test name="lang">
            <string>zh-cn</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
            <string>WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono</string> # Added by me
            <string>DejaVu Sans Mono</string>
            <string>Noto Sans Mono CJK SC</string>
            <string>WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono</string>
            <string>HYSong</string>
            <string>AR PL UMing CN</string>
            <string>AR PL UMing HK</string>
            <string>AR PL New Sung</string>
            <string>AR PL UKai CN</string>
            <string>AR PL ZenKai Uni</string>
        </edit>
    </match> 

</fontconfig>
```

---

Saving the changes and opening a new terminal, the characters are now rendered as desired:

[image]

After restarting the computer, one also sees the characters properly rendered in the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It looks like the Japanese font. Font series called Kozuka/小塚 or Mincho/明朝 will rending it as Google Docs, Firefox or Chrome your saw. Because the characters for both Japanese and Chinese have the same Unicode U+5916 for 外 and U+5C06 for 将. Try to switch to a Chinese font instead you will see the correct rending for Chinese Simplified look.